# Wordpress subdomain multisite

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I am installing a wordpress multisite, went through all the steps and made sure to select the subdomain option, but after its complete and I go to add a new site (lets say blog.example.com) it adds it but does not let me connect to the dashboard.

I created a blog.example.com entry into my cPanel for subdomains and put the document root as /public_html. I am at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong. Do I have to manually create a directory in my public_html/blog or just point it public_html. Does creating it do it for me? Am I to install Wordpress into public_html/blog before creating the site on the network admin? I followed several guides but it doesn't seem to be working when im trying to add sites.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it didn't like my temporary index.html I threw up as a temporary maintenance page...